# Adresses in virtual memory for Windows 32 bit mfc application.

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, 32-bit, virtual-memory

I have quite big MFC application for Windows only that I build with Visual Studio as 32bit production release version.

And I have some special class in my application that has int index member. That index is always equals to address of that object inside memory. And everything works fine.

However now i need to determine some space in virtual memory of my application that will for sure do not contain objects of that class.
When i see them in debugger so interval values are usually not some very low or very high but they are around some value. Can I safety assume that lets say addresses 0-10k (0x0000-0x2710) will do not contain those objects of that particular class? And if not is there some other address space that is 'safe'?

Or if there is not such a thing so maybe I can allocate some memory by myself to have dummy 'pool' that I can be sure no other objects will be created?

Comment: create separate heap, overwrite `operator new` for this class and allocate this objects from this heap

Comment: You can use `VirtualAlloc(MEM_RESERVE)` to allocate some address space. Nothing goes in that address space unless you put it there. Alternative: Windows will not put any objects in the bottom 64KB of memory (0x0000 through 0xFFFF). Prior to Windows 8, application could pull tricks to manually place objects there, but starting in Windows 8, that too is disallowed.

Comment: You are asking about your proposed solution. But what problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

This is all horribly system specific, but provided you can live with that limitation ...

- 0 will work if you only need a single item.
- Windows guarantees not to put any objects in the first 64K of memory, so any value less than 65536 is good. (Added after comment by Raymond Chen).
- If your code is not compiled with "large address space aware", you can use any address after 0x80000000.  (Unfortunately, if it *is*, although there is 1G reserved on 32 bit platforms, on 64 bit platforms your program has no reserved address space.)
- If your data has alignment requirements (and if it contains a 32-bit index, then it is almost certainly aligned at least 4 bytes), then any unaligned value will work.  In particular, any odd value will work. (Again, added after a comment by Raymond Chen).

Comment: Another option: If the object has alignment requirements, pick any unaligned value.